# Слайдер не работает

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, css

Здравствуйте . Слайдер сайта вдруг стал не работать в чем может быть проблема ? Использую CMS Wordpress слайдер Revolution Slider сначала работал вдруг стал не работать смотрел исходный код все загружается но не показывает слайдер . Загрузил Smart Slider тож та же проблема все загружается но не показывает слайдер .Easing Slider "Lite" загрузил нормально работает . В чем может быть проблема ? вот сайт http://doovad.com

Comment: другие слайды тоже работают

Answer (score 1):

так пишет же в консоли jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?rev=4.5.7&ver=4.0:25
Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined

Соответсвенно вы иницилизируете слайдер раньше чем загрузился DOM или у вас там с позиционированием блоков проблема и потому скрипт не может посчитать высоту.

Comment: дело в том что не изменял код вдруг стал не работать @binliz

Answer (score 0):

А не проверяли сайт на вирусы? Бывает, что вирусы меняют Java Script код.
Рекомендую попробовать плагин WordFence Security, помогает защитить сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Может конфликт Jquery? Дополнительно никакие скрипты не ставили?
Попробуйте после всех скриптов перед слайдером поставить `<script>jQuery.noConflict()</script>`